# How can I implement a checkerboard stride for Conv2d in pytorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to create a convnet using pytorch to work on an input of 2d matrices. I am using a 3x5 filter and I want it to have a custom stride as follows - on even line numbers I want the filter to start from the element at position 0 (red in the image), on odd line numbers I want it to start on the element of position 1 (blue in the image), and in both cases have a stride of 2 on the x direction. That means that if I have a matrix as in the image as my input, I want the filter to have only 0s in its center. I know this is very unusual in convnets but this is actually a problem in physics so the exact stride is important. [image: 3x5 filter on an input]

Comment: I guess the only thing I'm confused about is that some rows in your example have more anchor points than others (clear by counting the in each row). What would you expect the output shape of your conv operation to be in this example where the input width/height is 15?

Comment: You're right, in the real example there is another column and row so the number of 0s is equal between two different rows. The expected output in this case is therefore 6x7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following custom conv2d layer implements convolutions in a checkerboard stride as indicated in the original question. The difficulty here lies with the fact that pytorch doesn't really support inconsistent strides like this. That said we can break this operation into two separate strided convolutions, one for the even rows, and one for the odd rows. After that we can just interleave the results back together. There are some details in the code below which ensure we pad correctly (if desired). Also, this layer fully supports back-propagation.

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class AMNI_Conv2d(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, padding=0, bias=True):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, bias=bias, padding=padding)
        self.crow = self.conv.kernel_size[0] // 2
        self.ccol = self.conv.kernel_size[1] // 2

        # this module only works with odd sized kernels
        assert self.conv.kernel_size[0] % 2 == 1 and self.conv.kernel_size[1] % 2 == 1

    def forward(self, x):
        # currently only padding with zeros is supported
        if self.conv.padding[0] != 0 or self.conv.padding[1] != 0:
            x = F.pad(x, pad=(self.conv.padding[1], self.conv.padding[1], self.conv.padding[0], self.conv.padding[0]))

        # center filters on the "zeros" according to the diagram by AMNI, starting column for even/odd rows may need to change depending on padding/kernel size
        if (self.crow + self.ccol + self.conv.padding[0] + self.conv.padding[1]) % 2 == 0:
            x_even = F.conv2d(x[:, :, :-1, 1:], self.conv.weight, self.conv.bias, stride=2)
            x_odd = F.conv2d(x[:, :, 1:, :-1], self.conv.weight, self.conv.bias, stride=2)
        else:
            x_even = F.conv2d(x[:, :, :-1, :-1], self.conv.weight, self.conv.bias, stride=2)
            x_odd = F.conv2d(x[:, :, 1:, 1:], self.conv.weight, self.conv.bias, stride=2)
        b, c, h, w = x_even.shape

        # interleave even and odd rows back together
        return torch.stack((x_even, x_odd), dim=3).contiguous().view(b, c, -1, w)
```

---

**Example**

This layer basically acts like a normal Conv2d but with the checkerboard stride.

```
>>> x = torch.arange(64).view(1, 1, 8, 8).float()
tensor([[[[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.],
          [ 8.,  9., 10., 11., 12., 13., 14., 15.],
          [16., 17., 18., 19., 20., 21., 22., 23.],
          [24., 25., 26., 27., 28., 29., 30., 31.],
          [32., 33., 34., 35., 36., 37., 38., 39.],
          [40., 41., 42., 43., 44., 45., 46., 47.],
          [48., 49., 50., 51., 52., 53., 54., 55.],
          [56., 57., 58., 59., 60., 61., 62., 63.]]]])
```

---

```
>>> layer = AMNI_Conv2d(1, 1, (3, 5), bias=False)

# set kernels to delta functions to demonstrate kernel centers
>>> with torch.no_grad():
...     layer.conv.weight.zero_()
...     layer.conv.weight[:,:,1,2] = 1

>>> result = layer(x)
tensor([[[[10., 12.],
          [19., 21.],
          [26., 28.],
          [35., 37.],
          [42., 44.],
          [51., 53.]]]], grad_fn=<ViewBackward>)
```

You could also do this with padding to get every "zero" in the original diagram

```
>>> layer = AMNI_Conv2d(1, 1, (3, 5), padding=(1, 2), bias=False)

# set kernels to delta functions to demonstrate kernel centers
>>> with torch.no_grad():
...     layer.conv.weight.zero_()
...     layer.conv.weight[:,:,1,2] = 1

>>> result = layer(x)
tensor([[[[ 1.,  3.,  5.,  7.],
          [ 8., 10., 12., 14.],
          [17., 19., 21., 23.],
          [24., 26., 28., 30.],
          [33., 35., 37., 39.],
          [40., 42., 44., 46.],
          [49., 51., 53., 55.],
          [56., 58., 60., 62.]]]], grad_fn=<ViewBackward>)
```