# Implementing LeNet in Pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

Sorry if this question is incredibly basic. I feel like there is a wealth of resources online, but most of them are half-complete or skip over the details that I want to know.

I am trying to implement LeNet with Pytorch for practice.

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/neural_networks_tutorial.html

- How come in this examples and many examples online, they define the convolutional layers and the fc layers in init, but the subsampling and activation functions in forward?
- What is the purpose of using torch.nn.functional for some functions, and torch.nn for others? For example, you have convolution with torch.nn (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#conv1d) and convolution with torch.nn.functional (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#conv1d). Why choose one or the other?
- Let's say I want to try different image sizes, like 28x28 (MNIST). The tutorial recommends I resize MNIST. Is there a way to instead change the values of LeNet? What happens if I don't change them?
- What is the purpose of num_flat_features? If you wanted to flatten the features, couldn't you just do x = x.view(-1, 16*5*5)?

Comment: Generally SO requires one question per post. That said since these are fairly simple questions I'm posting answers to all of them. In the future please post one question at a time. You're much more likely to get an answer and you're also less likely to get a downvote.

Comment: Sorry about that - that's good to know. Thank you for the detailed answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How come in this examples and many examples online, they define the
>   convolutional layers and the fc layers in init, but the subsampling
>   and activation functions in forward?

Any layer with trainable parameters should be defined in `__init__`. Subsampling, certain activations, dropout, etc.. don't have any trainable parameters so can be defined either in `__init__` or used directly via the `torch.nn.functional` interface during `forward`.

> What is the purpose of using torch.nn.functional for some functions, and torch.nn for others?

The `torch.nn.functional` functions are the actual functions that are used at the heart of the majority of `torch.nn` layers, they call into C++ compiled code. For example `nn.Conv2d` subclasses `nn.Module`, as should any custom layer or model which contains trainable parameters. The class handles registering parameters and encapsulates some other necessary functionality required for training and testing. During `forward` it actually uses `nn.functional.conv2d` to apply the convolution operation. As mentioned in the first question, when performing a parameterless operation like ReLU there's effectively no difference between using the `nn.ReLU` class and the `nn.functional.relu` function.

The reason they are provided is they give some freedom to do unconventional things. For example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59005379/how-can-i-implement-a-checkerboard-stride-for-conv2d-in-pytorch) which I wrote the other day, providing a solution without `nn.functional.conv2d` would have been difficult.

> Let's say I want to try different image sizes, like 28x28 (MNIST). The
>   tutorial recommends I resize MNIST. Is there a way to instead change
>   the values of LeNet? What happens if I don't change them?

There's no obvious way to change an existing, trained model to support different image sizes. The size of the input to the linear layer is necessarily fixed and the number of features at that point in the model is generally determined by the size of the input to the network. If the size of the input differs from the size that the model was designed for then when the data progresses to the linear layers it will have the wrong number of elements and cause the program will crash. Some models can handle a range of input sizes, usually by using something like an `nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d` layer before the linear layer to ensure the input shape to the linear layer is always the same. Even so, if the input image size is too small then the downsampling and/or pooling operations in the network will cause the feature maps to vanish at some point, causing the program to crash.

> What is the purpose of num_flat_features? If you wanted to flatten the
>   features, couldn't you just do x = x.view(-1, 16*5*5)?

When you define the linear layer you need to tell it how large the weight matrix is. A linear layer's weights are simply an unconstrained matrix (and bias vector). The shape of the weight matrix therefore is determined by the input shape, but you don't know the input shape before you run forward so it needs to be provided as an additional parameter (or hard coded) when you initialize the model.

To get to the actual question. Yes, during `forward` you could simply use

```
x = x.view(-1, 16*5*5)
```

Better yet, use

```
x = torch.flatten(x, start_dim=1)
```

This tutorial was written before the `.flatten` function was added to the library. The authors effectively just wrote their own flatten functionality which could be used regardless of the shape of `x`. This was probably so you had some portable code that could be used in your model without hard coding sizes. From a programming perspective it's nice to generalize such things since it means you wouldn't have to worry about changing those magic numbers if you decide to change part of the model (though this concern didn't appear to extend to the initialization).